# WooCommerce subscriptions give option of manual renewal on checkout

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am trying to figure out how I can offer the option of manually renewing (automatic by default) a subscription on the checkout page. I would ideally like this to be a checkbox on the checkout page which is ticked by default saying 'automatically renew subscription'.

I can't seem to find any information on doing this so any input will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having done something similar recently:

Step 1: Add your checkbox as a custom checkout field (not covered here, you can easily find guides on how to do this).

Step 2: When the user submits their order at checkout, look for the manual renewal value in the submitted checkout data, and set it as meta on the WooCommerce order.

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta',function( $order_id) {    
    if(!empty($_POST['custom_manual_renewal'])){
        update_post_meta($order_id,'custom_manual_renewal',1);
    }
});
```

Step 3: When your subscription is created shortly after the order, look for your piece of meta and maybe set the subscription to manual.

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_subscription_created', function($subscription, $order){
    if(get_post_meta($order->get_id(),'custom_manual_renewal',true)){
        $subscription->update_manual(true); //set subscription to be manual renewal
    }
},10,2);
```